# Aptana 3 - Rails debugger not doing anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, aptana

When invoking "Debug Server" nothing happens at all, no error messages, nothing.
Also, nothing happens when opening a page in the browser that has breakpoints set in it.

In case i invoke "Debug as Ruby Application" i get the following exception:

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.6.1.beta2, debase 0.2.1, file filtering is supported) listens on 127.0.0.1:57291
Uncaught exception: uninitialized constant ApplicationController
    /home/jobmob/dev/jm10/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/jobmob/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `load'
    /home/jobmob/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/rdebug-ide:23:in `<main>'
```

But i think this is not the right way to debug a Rails appliation anyways, is it?

Here is my configuration:

- Aptana Studio 3.6.1 on CentOS 7
- Ruby 2.3.0
- Rails 4.2.6
- ruby-debug-ide 0.6.1 beta2